# Can I use Accompanist WebView as editor in jetpack compose?

Tags: webview, android-jetpack-compose, editor

Can I use somehow Accompanist WebView as editor?
I need something to to load html, but this field must be editable.

Comment: I think Accomanist Webview Is Going Deprecated and use You can enable Javascript so field will be editable

Answer (score 0):

**Accompanist WebView is already been deprecated**. I think it was also just a wrapper around traditional Webview with Androidview.

There is no specific API for Webview with compose as of now. But it's fine to use Webview inside AndroidView. You can **enable javascript** to make it editable and execute javascript.

```
var webView: WebView? = null
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                webView = WebView(context).apply {
                    // Run javascript to make it editable
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                }
                webView!!
            },
            update = { webView ->
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/")
            }
        )
        // evaluate javascript
        webView?.evaluateJavascript("console.log(\"Hello world\");", {})
```